# Weight selection of index from NSArray

Tags: ios, random, nsarray, probability

Given an NSArray of objects eg `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:A, B, C, D, E, nil]`, I can choose a random set of **N objects** from the array by using a `for loop` and an `arc4random` function e.g.

```
NSArray *objArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:A, B, C, D, E, nil];
NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int i=0;i<N;i++){

   id randIndex = arc4random() % N;
   [newArray addObject:[objArray objectAtIndex:randIndex];
}
```

This works fine, but what I'd like is to be able to specify a weighting for each of the elements in `objArray` that defines how likely that element is to be selected by the `randIndex`. It seems this selection could be dependent on previous selections (or not).

```
NSArray *weights = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@1, @0.5, @1, @1, @1]; would mean:

A - 1
B - 0.5 // 0.5 times as likely to appear
C - 0.3 // 0.3 times as likely to appear
D - 0.1 // 0.1x times as likely to appear
E - 0   // Will never appear
```

etc so the weights above would lead to having more object A's and no object E's. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS - How To Choose Objects in Array More-So Then Others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27383350/ios-how-to-choose-objects-in-array-more-so-then-others)

Comment: For the general case take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635448/generate-random-numbers-within-a-range-with-different-probabilities/13637027#13637027.

Comment: If you are giving probability of occurrence as weightage, how is probability of A = 1. This indicates A will be selected always. The sum of probabilities of all elements should be 1.